# Database and Models present still programming error is coming in DJango

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I am trying to get the models data on the browser using the urls.py and views.py for last 3 days and failing miserably, although I am able to get the database in a json file but not on browser. This is the error log [http://dpaste.com/2DQZX1Z][1] and the code is here

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Authors(models.Model):
    aid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    aname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    adescription = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)


class Books(models.Model):
    bid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bdescription = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)


class Bookauth(models.Model):
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Books, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='bid', blank=True, null=True)
    aid = models.ForeignKey(Authors, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='aid', blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import models
from .models import Books


import json
from django.core import serializers

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")


def getObject(request):
    all_books = Books.objects.all()
    html = serializers.serialize('json', all_books)
    return HttpResponse(html)
    #data = serializers.serialize("json", Books.objects.all())
    #return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^non', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^auth', views.author_search, name = 'AuthSearch'),
    url(r'^book', views.getObject, name = 'Books')
]
```

Comment: What happens when you ran manage.py migrate?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the error was with my my database too like I have changed the feilds in the models but not in MySql db  but now its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your models to this and then makemigrations then migrate and then check in the browser

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Authors(models.Model):
    aid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    aname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    adescription = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)


class Books(models.Model):
    bid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bdescription = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class Bookauth(models.Model):
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='bid', blank=True, null=True)
    aid = models.ForeignKey(Authors, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='aid', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: can you please tell me what you changed?

Comment: well you were providing 8000 characters for CharField which is not justfied, it can hold 255 characters, thus i changed it to TextField which can contain a large number of charaters, and you missed on_delete key before the models.DO_NOTHING